# Bash Terminal: How do I bind Ctrl+K to kill-whole-line THEN clear screen?

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, cygwin, conemu

basically I want to set a shortcut (ctrl+k) in my cygwin linux terminal to run

> bind '"\C-k": kill-whole-line'

THEN immediately run

> alias cls="echo -e '\033c\c'"

Both work by themselves but I would like to do it in one keyboard shortcut. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sequence clear current input and executes terminal reset.

```
bind '"\C-k": "\C-e\C-uecho -e \"\\033c\\c\"\n"'
```

Comment: Also, here are few other favourites: https://conemu.github.io/en/CygwinMsys.html#inputrc

Comment: It works but after it clears, there is a blank line above the cursor. http://i.imgur.com/HE42qfR.jpg

Comment: The `echo -e "\033c"` executed directly behaves the same way.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help Maximus!